# Google, Twitter authentication

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, twitter, google-api

I want to add on my site buttons to login via Google and Twitter. And I need to do it just using client side of application without server side. But I didn't find any API for that. For all things that I found, I need to use server side with secret key. Do you have any ideas if is it possible to do what I want? Thanks. P.S. I implemented such approach for Facebook, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For G+ take a look here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#using_the_client-side_flow

AFAIK Twitter has no client side solution - only the server side:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter